# Changing palindrome to fit numeric palindrome

Tags: java, palindrome

So I've figured out a pretty effective way to check palindromes, but I was asked to change it to fit a numeric palindrome and am again stuck.

```
public boolean checkNumericPalindrome() {

String s = this.s.toLowerCase();
String resultString = "";
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
      if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
         resultString = resultString + s.charAt(i);
      }
    }
int low = 0;
int high = resultString.length() - 1;

boolean isPalindrome = true;

while (low < high) {
  if (resultString.charAt(low) != resultString.charAt(high)) {
    isPalindrome = false;
    break;
  }

  low++;
  high--;
    }
return isPalindrome;
}
```

`

I've figured out that I had to change `Letters` to `isDigits`, and I know that I should change or get rid of `toLowerCase` and probably `s.length` but I can't seem to find the numeric equivalent, or know if there even is one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make any major changes to your logic, you can simply make string from your input number and do the same thing.

```
public boolean checkNumericPalindrome(int number) {
        String resultString = Integer.toString(number);
        //proceed with same logic & process string
        return true;
    }
```

**Edit:**
A better approach to do this:

```
public boolean checkNumericPalindrome(int number) {
     return checkStringPalindrome(Integer.toString(number));
}
```

So whenever you make changes to `checkStringPalindrome`, you don't need to change other methods.

Answer (score 0):

To check if an integer (aka numeric) value is a palindrome, reverse the digits and compare to original number:

```
private static long reverseDigits(long value) {
    long reverse = 0;
    for (; value != 0; value /= 10)
        reverse = reverse * 10 + value % 10;
    return reverse;
}

private static boolean isPalindrome(long value) {
    return (value == reverseDigits(value));
}
```

*Test*

```
private static void test(long value) {
    System.out.printf("%d <-> %d ==> %s%n", value, reverseDigits(value), isPalindrome(value));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(0);
    test(1);
    test(2);
    test(11);
    test(12);
    test(21);
    test(22);
    test(1234554321);
    test(1234565432);
    test(123456789987654321L);
}
```

*Output*

```
0 <-> 0 ==> true
1 <-> 1 ==> true
2 <-> 2 ==> true
11 <-> 11 ==> true
12 <-> 21 ==> false
21 <-> 12 ==> false
22 <-> 22 ==> true
1234554321 <-> 1234554321 ==> true
1234565432 <-> 2345654321 ==> false
123456789987654321 <-> 123456789987654321 ==> true
```